# Can I retrieve the result of a function using the SOAP API?

Tags: soap-api, developer-console, multi-currency, convertcurrency

I set up SOAP integration with my Salesforce instance, to maintain a copy of certain tables in our data warehouse.  This works great as long as I'm using fields enumerated in their SOAP API:

```
SforceService  service = InitializeApi();
foreach (sObject rawRecord in service.query("SELECT X, Y, Z FROM Opportunity").records)
    {
    var  opp = (Opportunity)rawRecord;
    SaveData(opp.Id, opp.AccountId, opp.RecordTypeId, opp.Amount);  // Etc.
    }
```

However, I'd like to get the converted values of currency fields. I'd like to call `convertCurrency()` and start capturing those values.  What I don't know is how to actually retrieve the values:

```
string  queryText = "SELECT Id, Amount, convertCurrency(Amount) AmountConverted FROM Opportunity";
foreach (sObject rawRecord in service.query(queryText).records)
    {
    var  opp = (Opportunity)rawRecord;
    SaveData(opp.AmountConverted);  // Does not exist
    }
```

Interestingly, if I run such a query in the Developer Console, the query executes without error, but I do not get any values for that function.  With this query:

```
SELECT SystemModStamp, TotalPrice, convertCurrency(TotalPrice) TotalPriceConverted
FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE OpportunityID = 'xxx'
```

...I get just two columns, `SystemModStamp` and `TotalPrice`.  Assuming Developer Console is using the SOAP API just like I am, I fear that there may be no way to retrieve this column.

Can anyone suggest a workaround?  Is this just not possible with the SOAP API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve both the raw and calculated value at once. Aliases only work in Aggregate Result queries. When using a function, the value itself is folded back into the field (e.g. TotalPrice), which is why you can't retrieve it twice.

## Examples

### No Translation

```
SELECT Name, StageName, Amount FROM Opportunity
```

## Results

```
Name, StageName, Amount
Opportunity 1, Prospecting, USD1000
```

### Translation

```
SELECT Name, toLabel(StageName), convertCurrency(Amount) FROM Opportunity
```

## Results

```
Name, StageName, Amount
Opportunity 1, Prospezione, EUR924.07
```

The reason why is because the translated values are meant for UI consumption, while the raw values are meant for API-only consumption (e.g. replication). Also, the translated value is of somewhat limited use, because it will only be converted to your user's currency, as opposed to any arbitrary currency.

Comment: "You can't retrieve both the raw and calculated value at once..." - so I can retrieve the calculated amount, as long as I don't also retrieve the local amount?  That's odd, but I don't mind running two queries.  Querying `SELECT Id, convertCurrency(Amount) Amount FROM Opportunity`, I do get values in the `Amount` column!  Would you like to expand upon that just a bit in your answer?

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Added an example, does that help?

Comment: That's perfect!  I got the answer that I needed, and it should be crystal clear for the next person who comes along too.  Thank you for sharing your experience.